# Error message when dismissing a UICloudSharingController

Tags: ios13, cloudkit, cloudkit-sharing

When a UICloudSharingController is dismissed I get the following error message:

```
-[_UIShareInvitationRemoteViewControllerTintColorView _accessibilityUnregisterRemoteView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have no idea what this means. Has anyone come across something similar?

Comment: Did you manage to fix that? I have the same problem.